# How to install audiodiff?

Tags: python-3.x

So i am trying to install [audiodiff](https://pypi.org/project/audiodiff/) via anaconda prompt. The error i keep getting is related to mutagen. But i have installed  mutagenwrapper and  mutagen and its their installation that i think is causing the issue has anyone else had that issue and solved it?

The error I get is command "python setup.py egg info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\TEST\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0rsg6wwr\mutagen\

However if i try to install mutagen it just says requirement already satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only supported in python 2.7